# How to pass environment variables to the maven-release-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I am using the `maven-release-plugin` to create a release. The project builds just fine and I've already released it a number of times. Now I need to use an environment variable. Since the `maven-release-plugin` uses the `maven-invoker`, it's forking a new shell and, unfortunately, the environment variable is getting lost.

Is there a way to control the behavior of the passing of environment variables to the forked process? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you try with using system properties? Also can you share maven release plugin and invoker plugin configuration.

Comment: Why do you need to have environment variables during the release process? What is being controlled / changed by that..?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement recently and managed to do it as follows. Posting it here in case anyone else finds this useful.

First, in the pom.xml, add an environment variable to the plugin which needs the environment variable and set its value to refer to a system property. e.g.,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>publish</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>bal</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>push</argument>
                </arguments>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <ACCESS_TOKEN>${dev.token}</ACCESS_TOKEN>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then, when running the `mvn` command, pass the environment variable through the `dev.token` system property. e.g.,

```
$ mvn release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-Ddev.token=$ENV_VAR_NAME"
```

The `arguments` system property basically passes the value set to it as the arguments list to the forked process. So we're basically passing on the environment variable value to the forked process through a system property.